# how do we organise a linked-list recurrence relation to merge two sorted linked list?

Tags: python, linked-list

I have edited the code to incorporate the notes from below (from Trincot), the only thing I am still not clear about is the "l1.next= MergeTwoLists(l1.next,l2)" ; I still don't think this is right- any ideas how to amend this?

Also, do I need a while statement, since the recursive call seems to loop in some sense already.

```
Input: l1 = [1,2,4], l2 = [1,3,4]
Output: [1,1,2,3,4,4]


def MergeTwoLists(l1,l2):
    prehead = ListNode(-1)
    pointer_run = prehead

    #Base Case
    if not l1:
        return l2
    if not l2:
        return l1


    #Recurrence Relation
    while l1 or l2: 
        if l1.val < l2.val:
            pointer_run.next = l1
            l1_temp = l1.val
            l1.next= MergeTwoLists(l1.next,l2)

        else:
            pointer_run.next = l2
            l2.next = MergeTwoLists(l1,l2.next)


    return prehead.next
```

Comment: What is `l1` and `l2`?

Comment: Sorry- let me edit

Comment: `lists` dont have an attribute `val` or `next`. You need to make a [mcve]

Comment: You never actually put the `.val` values in the result; it recurses all the way through to the empty lists, which returns `None`, and then that `None` is passed back up as the final result

Comment: Sabik, how do I put the .val values in the result?? I thought by linking pointer_run to l1,l2,l1.next, etc this is passing the values no?

Comment: Your input/output at the top is misleading: you present them as Python lists, but then in your code they suddenly seem to be linked lists for which you have not provided the initialisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am getting None as the output.

This happens when `l2.val == l1.val`. This is a case that is not captured by any `if` in your code, and so `prehead.next` is executed. But that `next` attribute never received a value other than the initial value, which I suppose is set to `None` by the `ListNode` constructor.

There are the following issues:

- The last `if` should really be an `else`, as you want to capture the above described case in one of those two blocks. As both these blocks (the `if` block and now `else` block) end with a `return`, there should be no possibility to ever get to `return prehead.next`: that statement can be removed. That also means that `prehead` is never *read* after its `next` attribute is assigned a value, and therefore serves no purpose.
- `return MergeTwoLists(l1.next,l2)` is not correct. You need to assign the returned value to `l1.next`. And to avoid that you mutate the input lists, you should first make a new node with the value at `l1` and assign to that new node's `next` attribute. The same is true for the mirrored situation.
- The first base case is not necessary, as it is covered by the next.

As `ListNode` was not given, I add the definition that I will use in the corrected code:

```
class ListNode:
    # Constructor allows caller to optionally provide a next node
    def __init__(self, val, nxt=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = nxt

    # A method to ease the iteration of all list values
    def values(self):
        yield self.val
        if self.next:
            yield from self.next.values()

    # Define the representation of a list (e.g. for printing)
    def __repr__(self):
        return " → ".join(map(repr, self.values()))

    # A class method to ease the creation of a list
    @classmethod
    def fromvalues(cls, *values):
        head = None
        for val in reversed(values):
            head = cls(val, head)
        return head
```

Here is the corrected function:

```
def MergeTwoLists(l1, l2):
    if not l1:
        return l2
    if not l2:
        return l1
    if l1.val < l2.val:
        return ListNode(l1.val, MergeTwoLists(l1.next, l2))
    else:
        return ListNode(l2.val, MergeTwoLists(l1, l2.next))
```

Here is how you can run it:

```
l1 = ListNode.fromvalues(1, 2, 4) 
l2 = ListNode.fromvalues(1, 3, 4)
result = MergeTwoLists(l1, l2)
print(result)  # 1 → 1 → 2 → 3 → 4 → 4
```